# Index Stemming to process text in C# or ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, indexing, stemming

Given this text:

"Friends are friendlier friendlies that are friendly and classify the friendly classification class. Flowery flowers flow through following the flower flows"

I need to apply stemming to the text to achieve the following outcome:

```
frequency("following")                = 1
frequency("flow")                     = 2
frequency("classification")           = 1
frequency("class")                    = 1
frequency("flower")                   = 3
frequency("friend")                   = 4
frequency("friendly")                 = 4
frequency("classes")                  = 1
```

As we interface with the FAST search engine. FAST indexes content to provide relevant search results to a query. One aspect of indexing is stemming and we need to use either C# or ruby to solve this.

Would appreciate anyone's views on the best approach

Comment: Are you asking for a stemming algorithm?

Comment: Most likely http://github.com/nhsevidence/interviews

Comment: "As we interface with the FAST search engine. FAST indexes content to provide relevant search results to a query. One aspect of indexing is stemming and we need to use either C# or ruby to solve this." What's with the "we" talk? The "Royal we"? Sounds more like an assignment of some type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public StemmingProcessorResults ProcessText(string text)
    {
            return new StemmingProcessorResults(
                    new []{
                        new StemmingProcessorResultItem("following", 1),
                        new StemmingProcessorResultItem("flow", 2),
                        new StemmingProcessorResultItem("classification", 1),
                        new StemmingProcessorResultItem("class", 1),
                        new StemmingProcessorResultItem("flower", 3),
                        new StemmingProcessorResultItem("friend", 4),
                        new StemmingProcessorResultItem("friendly", 4),
                        new StemmingProcessorResultItem("classes", 1)
                    }
                );
    }
```

There you go, that should be perfect for your copy-paste needs

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "apply stemming" to the text to get those results because the acceptance criteria contains a mistake.  Namely frequency("friend") should be 5.  Every single **stemming** algorithm *by definition* cannot produce the acceptance criteria.  Therefore *any* algorithm that gives those values will have to do - as per Rob Ashton.  You could also use a switch statement or a dictionary lookup, whatever, it just needs to output those numbers.